# How to submit text messages to server via ios apps

Tags: ios

my problem is I cannot send the text messages to server. Im using asihttprequest. I have define the USERNAME, UUID, PASSWORD, API_PASSWORD and NUMBER myself. What I want to do is just send the data to the server url given. Here is my code:

```
    - (IBAction)sendClicked:(id)sender {

    [sendButton resignFirstResponder];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:@"https://cc.frifon.net_dosmssend/"]];
    [request setDelegate:self];
     [request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:3];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setPostValue:USERNAME forKey:@"sip"];
    [request setPostValue:PASSWORD forKey:@"pwd"];
    [request setPostValue:UUID forKey:@"uuid"];
    [request setPostValue:API_PASSWORD forKey:@"key"];
    [request setPostValue:messageText forKey:@"message"];
    [request setPostValue:NUMBER forKey:@"to"];
    [request setPostValue:@"Submit" forKey:@"submit"];
       [request start];
    nil;

    [request startAsynchronous];
     }

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
    messageText.text = response;
}

}
```

Comment: You can use a simple php script too, then you can send the string in an HTML format to the server and the php script will do the rest for you. You send the string like that www.yourserver.com/script.php?request=Your%20Request It may be a dumb idea, but this is my thought.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (IBAction)sendClicked:(id)sender {

    [sendButton resignFirstResponder];
    NSString *serviceString = https://cc.frifon.net_dosmssend/;
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[serviceString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]]];
    [request setDelegate:self];
     request.requestMethod = @"POST";
    request.timeOutSeconds = 30.0;
    [request addPostValue:USERNAME forKey:@"sip"];
    [request addPostValue:PASSWORD forKey:@"pwd"];
    [request addPostValue:UUID forKey:@"uuid"];
    [request addPostValue:API_PASSWORD forKey:@"key"];
    [request addPostValue:messageText forKey:@"message"];
    [request addPostValue:NUMBER forKey:@"to"];
    [request addPostValue:@"Submit" forKey:@"submit"];

    [request startAsynchronous];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)sendClicked:(id)sender {
 // Add you all data in below dictionary 
 NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"action":@"login",@"nick_name":nikname,@"password":pass};
 NSError *error;
 NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&error];

 NSString *jason =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSLog(@"JSON summary: %@", jason);

 NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"www.demo.com"];

 address=  [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:address];

 NSLog(@"%@",address);

 // request creation
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowedInMemoryOnly
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:data];

 responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];       

NSURLConnection *Conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[Conn start];
}
```